# Is it possible to decide the return type of a function at runtime, based on a function argument?

Tags: typescript

This is best explained with an example!

```
interface Query {
  foo: any;
}

interface Mutation {
  bar: any;
}

type OperationName = keyof Query | keyof Mutation;

const request = async <T>(args, operationName: OperationName): Promise<{ data: { [operationName]: T } }> => {

};
```

Ideally what I want to happen is if I call `request` like this:

```
const result = await request<string>({}, 'foo');
```

then `result` looks like this:

```
{
  data: {
    foo: string
  }
}
```

However this gives the error `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type. ts(1170)`

I feel like this *should* be possible as the type `OperationName` is known at compile time so there should be some way for the compiler to figure out all the possible return types of `request` in advance. I've no idea how to do it though!

Comment: `keyof Query & keyof Mutation` is `never`, those types have no overlapping keys...

Comment: `as` just says "this is this type" and does no changes or conversions. If you have data, return the data as you wish to return it. If the returned types could be different, the *caller* then has to *narrow* the type to know what to use.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bad, should be a union, not an intersection!

Comment: @crashmstr Sorry, I haven't explained what I'm trying to do. Normally I'd leave it up to the caller as you say, but as this is a library function being used by loads of people, I'd rather have its behaviour be as clear as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer only discusses how to *type* the function properly, not *do* the conversion at runtime.

You must implement yourself the conversion somehow (based on operation, arguments passed, etc).

You can use a mapped type here:

```
const request = async <T, O extends OperationName>(args: unknown, operationName: O): Promise<{ data: { [K in O]: T } }> => {
```

We need another generic parameter `O` which is an OperationName to "retain" what was passed to `operationName`. Then we use a mapped type which maps `O` to `T`.

But we aren't done quite yet. Notice that when we call it:

```
request<string>(???, "foo")
```

We get an error because we didn't provide a parameter for `O`. We can pass `"foo"` again but that is redundant, so we'll work around it by currying:

```
const request = <T>() => async <O extends OperationName>(args: unknown, operationName: O): Promise<{ data: { [K in O]: T } }> => {
```

Now we can pass `T` separate of `O`:

```
request<string>()(???, "foo")
```

[Playground with example calls](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdoE9kG8CwAUMsjAPZkBcycIWA3EQL5FGiSyIoCy6YcYYGRB4iJAEZwo1Wg2atCAekXIAzgAsy6ADYATZOJQB5AErJ10CETBYADsftQBQkADk4AWxQBeZAGsILDIYNEwoHAAff0Dg5F5+QWFGQiJlZGBdP2QAd3UBGigAc1V01SIEYVUwZCgIAEdMKuRfAB4AFQA+AAoASmaOmlUsEARkFqNkCAAPSBBdEqNHZ2F3L26pYup0ED8QMmyQABpkMiXEt08IaiMe6gAFKDIPYFUIFtxkXQE4ag+AbQA0ukREYALrUNrIJhQgbeAYEYjINIAETIajA6BgMAAdLixEiVEF0MgPOgmsAPLZtBAvOBkGALMgKiAAG7QVQuZBEqCvbQhVRPCCabL42oYqAiEA6bQAQmSTGS5Uq1V0AEZmjV6o0wC0qlBQIVuj0ugAGY4AInIZHNPWSaRIyAAegB+BTMpq6ABMGtqDQgVRaUo8higRtNFskUBtdpUDpdQA)

Comment: Very clever, I hadn't thought of currying it! I wish I had more than one upvote for this. The return value is coming from a request to an external service, so that handles the creation of the eventual result. It's been bugging me for so long that I haven't been able to do it in a type-safe way!