# How to override a generic type's property with an argument's typeof value in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I am trying to create a generic type check function that checks if an object's property has a type. But it would be nice if I didn't need to define the field as both an argument value and type value.

For example, this works but feels a bit redundant:

```
function isFieldPopulated<T1, T2, K extends keyof T1>(doc: T1, field: K): doc is Omit<T1, K> & Record<K, T2> {
    // check if T1[K] is a T2
    return ...;
}

if (isFieldPopulated<Post, Category, 'category'>(data, 'category')) {
    // data.category is a Category type
}
```

I was hoping not to have to set 'category' here `<Post, Category, 'category'>` AND here `(data, 'category')`. Is there a way for TS to know that the `field` argument extends keyof T1 without having to specifically put 'category' inside `<..., 'category'>` since it's already being passed through as a string argument?

UPDATE:
Here is a [minimal working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFA3gfQEsATALigGdg1CA7JAXwG4BYAKFEigAUUrs8AYwTJ0IclRr0oAH1gjUGADRRghYABsIE6nUas27QSlr9iCOOV78cAClsBKbAD487KB6jHTwKEWICAERwAEaCAIwATADMgQaeXib8aprQOIFgfL4pWnHunt78woiKmDgAIiIAdLQoAO6OUACkUJHYWDgADFAA-Hj%20DFDk-vGeaBDAAK5otEIKYio5EMzsDA6O7OwAZpO0gmomUIQUAPIhAFYQ%207YAbnAa5HC0IA7kISgoWk9ubAnjUzMoHcNFAAGSg1TgCAoLZA%207tHAAchQFyuwERYIhwKqhWok326ARUDOl32BgYmzYOz2B1mxwAYoQIBpiLwwJMNCJiAAeAAq4RUvMiKgA0lAIAAPRC0YgUKAAawgIBhUH5zlsxBQgnI-JUWyZLPIIteUE1giOcv5YKgACUrugeSLBZFXLh8h5-tM6adUdczQBtfXM4gAXQc5MpAHpI1A6uh5XKQpNfABJKAACzgN2gwBQlAmUERxVEGAxdCg72A6ag3KqdZURfmpdcTwCtjrVQbxdKiIc7EIsNsDINrJQ7M5iB51mAKngJQWhe7YkR6vMwDgXabIF7TjdvwKSU%20ECqGhQSA1FhxW-DUGjpsvS4wFqgcHk84w7sSpiPJ7PF-XVRLDed5rnAgHqFoz6SHoqyUtS%20yEIcw7BmyHJcgA6uo6YoMmIp8gKqouhqWo6gRQaGgqSoqvyJpms%20VoQnaxhoDynDQrC5HEM6rqfp6gLHCSaLEYIgYjmGEaGGwIEoBApiIr4cZoPKL4yqo6Z0AmakIC%20GggmAaBjnKcDjG%20JaYP2g7ISyqEThAxCYVWOHAHh06zluq4WJu77bg4u6foUP6nueoFXt5wExiFj6YMcL6maU-mHlov7BZeQFMLeEWpRB0Axa%20c5mbBbBAA).

Comment: What is the type of `data`? Do you have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally others could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mp9Z7W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: OK updated my post with a link to a working example.

Comment: Is the type you pass to `isFieldPopulated` the one that is enforced or is it only object types (no primitives)? [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mLlEkm) is an example of the latter. The type is `(string | Category) & Category` but that simplifies to just `Category`.

Comment: Thanks @catgirlkelly, T2 is the one that should be enforced.

Comment: You can use currying like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71873154/18244921) to preserve the inferred types while still retaining the type you want to check in a fluent manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because TypeScript can already infer `T1` and `K` correctly for us, there should be no need to explicitly provide `T2`. It seems that you want only the object types and not primitives (like `string`), so we can give `T2` the type `Extract<T1[K], object>`, giving us all the object types in `T1[K]`:

```
function isFieldPopulated<T1, T2 extends Extract<T1[K], object>, K extends keyof T1>(doc: T1, field: K): doc is T1 & Record<K, T2> {
```

You can verify that it works [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFA3gfQEsATALigGdg1CA7JAXwG4BYAKFEigAUUrs8AYwTJ0IclRr0oAH1gjUGADRRghYABsIE6nUas27QSlr9iCOOV78cAClsBKbAD487KB6jHTwKEWICAERwAEaCAIwATADMgQaeXib8aprQOIFgfL4pWnHunt78woiKmDgAIiIAdLQoAO6OUACkUJHYWDgADFAA-Hj+DFDk-vGeaBDAAK5otEIKYio5EMzsDA6O7OwAZpO0gmomUIQUAPIhAFYQ+7YAbnAa5HC0IA7kISgoWk9ubAnjUzMoHcNFAAGSg1TgCAoLZA+7tHAAchQFyuwERYIhwKqhWok326ARUDOl32BgYmzYOz2B1mxwAYoQIBpiLwwJMNCJiAAeAAq4RUvLaEAAHohaMQKFAAKJitBwfZ88IAbQA0gBdFQo0nAZwqVVQUXiyVQADWEBAMKg-OctmIKEE5H5Ki2TJZ5FVryg9sERyl-LBUAASld0DzVYLIq5cPkPP9pnTTqjrj7la7mcR1Q5yZTCLDbAy3ayUOzOYhiHaLCpEcVRBhEQ4nDHfgUkp8IFUNCgkJXgHAcfMMNmoAB6EfeiwDkpiP1QODyacYWOJUztzvd3v9pbDscTvtVJazyR6VbsIA).